# KeyEventCompat not supported at build

Tags: android, keyevent

My project is currently using but seems I have moved to api level 26 - revision 26.0.2, I am struggling to find the symbol `KeyEventCompat`

```
import android.support.v4.view.KeyEventCompat;
```

I try to figure out using `v7` but it's not working. Any idea on how to make it works.

Example of use:

```
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB:
    if (KeyEventCompat.hasNoModifiers(event)) {
        handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_FORWARD);
    } else if (KeyEventCompat.hasModifiers(event, KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON)) {
        handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_BACKWARD);
    }
    break;
```

Any idea on how to make it works.

Thanks

Comment: [The class has been deprecated](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2707)... what exactly are you trying to do with that class?

Comment: catching event. the project is done since a while but we are updating it

Comment: What event are you trying to catch? Can you post a code snippet on what you are trying to do? I think you'll get better help asking people how you can replace the deprecated class than keep using it.

Comment: done. I have added a code snippet

Comment: What API's are you supporting? I did some more reading and it looks like KeyEventCompat was deprecated because KeyEvent supports the minimum support library (API 14). So, if you support anything lower than API 14, you'll probably run into other issues with the support libraries. The `hasNoModifiers` call requires API 11+, btw.

Comment: minimum supported is 19 and the target is 26

Comment: @sed did you get any solution ?

Comment: @TusharLathiya You can check my answer

Answer (score 89, accepted):

change this

```
if (KeyEventCompat.hasNoModifiers(event)) {
    handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_FORWARD);
} else if (KeyEventCompat.hasModifiers(event, KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON)) {
    handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_BACKWARD);
}
```

to

```
if (event.hasNoModifiers()) {
    handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_FORWARD);
} else if (event.hasModifiers(KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON)) {
    handled = arrowScroll(FOCUS_BACKWARD);
}
```

[KeyEventCompat](https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/26.0.0-alpha1/changes/android.support.v4.view.KeyEventCompat) class was deprecated in API level 26.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Since you are supporting API 19+, change your `KeyEventCompat` calls to `KeyEvent` calls. You should be able to get comparable functionality at that API level.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this KeyEventCompat issue by adding this line to the app's build gradle (Above dependencies)

```js
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'

    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.2'
            }
        }
    }
}
```